# Putting every word in a file into an array list

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

New to Buffered Readers and I am trying to put a file into an array list... This is what I have so far.

```
  FileReader in = new FileReader(latestFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

    int arrayCount = 0;
    String[] array = null;

    String nextLine = null;
    if ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null ) {
        arrayCount = array.length;
        array[arrayCount - 1] = nextLine.split("\\s+");

    }
```

Can anyone explain what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you be more precise about your problem ?

Comment: Aside from using a `List<String>` mentioned in answers, you would benefit from using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) constructed from your `BufferedReader` to read words, rather than reading a line and splitting it

Answer (score 1):

Just change `String[] array = null;` to `List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();` and `array[arrayCount - 1] = nextLine.split("\\s+");` to `arrayList.add(nextLine.split("\\s+"));`.

I.e. use `ArrayList` instead of undefined array.

Comment: Just tried the second part where you add the arraylist. It keeps producing an error at the add part. I also addAll, but that didnt work.

Comment: What error??? It is so hard to provide stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourfile.txt"));

ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

String line;
while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) 
{
    array.add(line.split("\\s+"));
}
file.close();
```

Basically you read your file line by line and add each line to your ArrayList of Strings.

And if you want to access the elements you can do it this way:

```
for (int i=0; i < array.size(); i++)
   System.out.println(array.get(i));
```

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but that doesnt seperate them by word. From my printout it seems like it separates them based on rows.

Comment: You're right, I edited the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- The Problem is  you've not initialized the `Array` object and to do that, you have to know the number of elements that you're going to read from the file.
  So you can initialize the array as

  ```
  String[] array = new String[The Number];
  ```
- Since it is unlikely that you know the number of elements that will be in the array, you have to use an `ArrayList`.

  ```
  FileReader in = new FileReader(latestFile);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

  // This list will dynamically grow as elements are inserted.
  ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

  String nextLine = null;
  if ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null ) {
    arraylist.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split("\\s+")));
  }

  // if you want an array, following code will return all the 
  //elements as String array
  String[] array = arraylist.toArray(new String[0]);
  ```

  Using an `ArrayList` would be easy.

  Hope this helps.